# jQuery Portlet/Sortable Flickers Screen in IE(checked with 8,9)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have jQuery UI portlet in my code which works well in all other browser as per the requirement but in IE when I start dragging any portlet it flickers the whole screen.
Any solutions or any Suggestion???

I found this from the jQuery forum
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7351

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own portlet-style implementation seems to be working in IE9, as well as IE9 in IE8 mode (do not have a native IE8 handy).

I also had flickering, but even in Chrome and Firefox. I just kept picking through the CSS and turning on and off various properties. Eventually I identified that I had applied a class that made my "portlet" take absolute positioning and that the jQuery UI interaction did not like that. By best guess is that the conflict between the CSS absolute positioning and the absolute positioning applied by dragging was causing it to jump back and forth between its original position and the new position. Worse yet, I couldn't position reliably at the top or bottom of my sortable containers.

Bottom line: I got rid of absolute positioning on the portlet (portlet contents can still have absolute positioning as long as the parent is relatively positioned) and everything worked smoothly for all target browsers.

Comment: your answer worked for me but some where i have to use position:absolute in my code on top div of the .column
so let me know if you have any idea how it can be solved? i m trying to get the solution too...

Comment: No idea. All I can think is that you can use the API to add and remove a class that will set it as "absolute". Remove the absolute as the move starts, and add it back in the "update" callback?